# New Android Studio projects don't show in "Android" structure view and XML files cannot initialize

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Platform: Mac OS 10.15.5, AS Version: Android Studio 4.0, build AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223 from JB Toolbox, Gradle version for projects: Gradle-6.1.1-all

I think this started after this one time where Gradle was running to build for like 15 minutes I thought "This is taking too long and restarted Android Studio (First stopping Gradle)."

I deleted the project since it proved unsuccessful (It was testing Intel Multi-OS Engine) and I went to start a new project.

For some reason all new projects now cannot display the "Android" Structure view (This also brings no run configurations so I can't build the app either) and XML files for the UI cannot be edited, first saying  in Design view "Design Editor is unavailable until next Gradle sync" and then after syncing again, it just says "Failed to initialize editor." Restarting the IDE and computer did nothing, I thought this was a problem with Gradle so I deleted ~/.gradle, but still no results.

Mind you existing projects still work. I'm gonna try to reinstall Android Studio tomorrow, but it's not a great time since I'm also starting a group project with others using it tomorrow. What could be the cause of this?

(Can't post an image b/c of reputation)

Comment: have you tried deleting `.idea` folder and all `.iml` files, closing project and reopening? Also before deleting Android Studio consider deleting its configuration files, they may live in your home folder instead of where you think. Not a mac user so can't help. I also tend to find 4.0 a bit less stable than 3.6 so I wouldn't discard it as well. Finally, if you cancel/stop gradle, consider hitting the button that forces gradle to refresh inside Android Studio. Last, to rule out problems with gradle do `./gradlew assembleDebug`, if it works then it's not gradle's fault.

Comment: Ok so I tried all of those and it still doesn't fix the project or any new projects. I even downgraded to 3.6.3 and the same problem arises. I know Android Studio stores templates in its preferences, but there are also templates in my Android SDK directory. If downgrading and upgrading back up doesn't fix those (and Gradle is not the problem), then I think I have to re-install my SDK to fix the templates (or parts of it like Android Platform API 29 and 30 which are the ones I use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok yeah just reinstalled and now it works again. I knew that somehow the templates got corrupted or lost some files.